# How to check if item exists in another listview?

Tags: vb.net

So I have two listviews. I want to check to see if the item X in Listview1 already exists in ListView2 and if it does change the color of the item in ListView2.

```
For Each itm As ListViewItem In Form1.ListView1.Items
    If itm.SubItems(0).Text.Contains(stringJoined) Then
        itm.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Where does `stringJoined` magically come from?  If that's supposed to come from `itm` then you need some code to make that happen.

Comment: It is already declared in an above statement.

Comment: You should have shown it's declaration in the code - post all and only relevant code - but what use is declaring it if you never set it's value?  You ask about how to compare two `ListViews` but there's only one `ListView` in that code.  You're comparing to `stringJoined` so it should be obvious that the value of `stringJoined` must come from the other `ListView`.  Where's that happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second listview's `Items.ContainsKey` method:

```
For Each itm As ListViewItem In Form1.ListView1.Items

    ' Check for item is ListView2
    If Form1.ListView2.Items.ContainsKey(itm.Key) Then
        ' Set BackColor to Red
        Form1.ListView2.Items.Item(itm.Key).BackColor = Color.Red
    End If

Next
```

This assumes you populated both listviews with keys and that both items would have the same key.